# "Error in SQL statement: SparkException: Exception thrown in Future.get"

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

So I'm trying to run an SQL query in databricks. I ran a similar one earlier today that worked with no issues. I took that query, negated one of the lines, and I keep getting this error after about 4 mins of run time: "Error in SQL statement: SparkException: Exception thrown in Future.get"

Here's the line: `sgrp_cd not in (7520)`

If I change this to `sgrp_cd in (7520)`, it runs. When I say `not in`, I get the error. I'm baffled. I've run similar queries with `not in` in the past and it was fine so truly not sure what I'm missing.

I thought maybe it was the syntax so I tried `<>` and `ne` and those don't work either (`<>` gives same error, `ne` just doesn't work at all)

I can't share any more but it has to be this line because it runs fine without it. Any idea? I can't find much info about this error online.

Thanks.

UPDATE:
I had a range join optimization at beginning (that worked fine with the first query!), but in desperation I took that out and now it runs... not as critical but still curious if anybody knows why this weird thing is happening.